In-place operations in gradient computation in nested PyTorch loops
I'm developing a PyTorch-based model that utilizes nested loops for calculations.
I've encountered a roadblock when attempting to compute gradients. The backpropagation process fails due to what appears to be in-place operations within the loops.
Here's a minimal example illustrating the problem:
import torch

# Setup
length, dx = 1000, 100
num_rows, num_cols = 5, int(length / dx) + 1

# Parameters requiring gradients
C = torch.rand(num_rows, requires_grad=True)
D = torch.rand(num_rows, requires_grad=True)
qobs = torch.rand(num_rows)

# Intermediate calculations
Caux = 1 + C + D
C0, C1, C2 = (-1 + C + D) / Caux, (1 + C - D) / Caux, (1 - C + D) / Caux

# Main computation
qprop = torch.zeros((num_rows, num_cols))
qprop[:, 0] = qobs

for j in range(1, num_cols):
    for n in range(1, num_rows):
        qprop[n, j] = (C2[n] * qprop[n-1, j-1] +
                       C1[n] * qprop[n, j-1] +
                       C0[n] * qprop[n-1, j])

# Attempt gradient computation
loss = qprop.sum()
loss.backward()  # This operation fails


You cannot change variables when their content would be required to compute the gradient in the back propagation state, this throws the error. You can circumvent this by changing the variable from being a leaf variable to a changeable one by cloning it. See https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/in-place-operation-when-indexing-target-variable-with-bytetensor/15839 for a solution
